# Convert InboundJaxrsResponse to json string

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0, javax.ws.rs

I am trying to serialize a jax-rs Response to json string.

The response from the server is json, and I get it from jersey client with:

```
Response resp = target.request().method("PUT", Entity.json(payloadBean))
```

where payloadBean is my json request. Everything works fine but I cannot convert the resp in json string in order to log it.

If I try:

```
String s = EntityUtils.toString((HttpEntity) resp.getEntity());
```

I get:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector cannot be cast to org.apache.http.HttpEntity
```

By the way if I don't cast to HttpEntity, compiler says:

```
toString (org.apache.http.HttpEntity) in EntityUtils cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object).
```

My relevant imports are:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I needed to buffer the message entity data since the stream was consumed and I was getting an error later when I was trying to re-read the response. Thus in order to log it first and then use it again I had to:

```
resp.bufferEntity();  //need to buffer entity, in order to read the entity multiple times from the Response's InputStream
String s = resp.readEntity(String.class);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`resp.readEntity(String.class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-)

> `public abstract <T> T readEntity(Class<T> entityType)`
>
> **Type Parameters:**
>       `T` - entity instance Java type.
>
> **Parameters:**
>       `entityType` - the type of entity.
>
> Read the message entity input stream as an instance of specified Java type using a MessageBodyReader that supports mapping the message entity stream onto the requested type.

Comment: If I try this to case (a) I get: "Error reading from entity from input stream", with details message "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.apache.http.HttpEntity, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@1c802d1d; line: 1, column: 1]"

Comment: Why are you trying to create an HttpEntity. If you want JSON, create a POJO. That's what Jackson is trying to do, convert the JSON into a POJO of type HttpEntity. It can't, so you are getting the exception. If don't want to create a POJO, then just extract it as a String and work with the String.

Comment: ok I got it. The thing is that the response could represent a lot of different POJO classes, thus I was looking for a generic way to parse any structured json response. Anyway thank you for your time

Comment: Use `readEntity(new GenericType<Map<String, Object>>(){});`. That will give you a `Map<String, Object>`, but trying to traverse it for random structures may not be so trivial for more complex structures

Comment: Actual answer is below! Thanks!